# How to display images in webpage in django with multiple apps

Tags: django

I currently have 2 applications.
When I first made the first app it was displaying the images correctly. I would upload the images in the admin console then the image would be displayed in the webpage. Feeling confident I made another app on the same project with a different purpose but recycled the code to display images and now both apps are no working.

The directory

```
crm
|_crm
   |_settings.py
   |_urls.py
   |_wsgi.py
   |_*.py
|_website(app1)
   |_*.py
   |_templates
       |_*.html
|_media
   |_images.png
|_gamot(app2)
   |_*.py
   |_templates
       |_*.html
|_manage.py
```

**Main/Global files**
Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_FILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('gamot/', include('gamot.urls'),name='gamot'),
    path('crm/', include('website.urls'),name='crm'),

]
```

**App Files**

View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import SignUpForm,AddRecordForm
from .models import *
def upload_image(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=1)
    return render(request,'upload.html',{'person':person})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=False,upload_to='img/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('upload',views.upload_image, name='add_record'),

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<h1> Upload</h1>

<img src="{{ person.image.url }}" alt="My image" width=500>
<br>
<img src="{{ person.image }}" alt="My image" width=500>
<br>
{{person.image }}
<br>
{{person.image.url }}

{% endblock %}
```

Display

```
Upload
My image
My image
img/sample.png
/media/img/sample.png
```

Terminal Output

```
[09/Jul/2023 07:56:57] "GET /media/img/sample.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2344
Not Found: /crm/img/sample.png
```

Comment: `def upload_image` this view is unable to _upload_ anything. Show the real code which handles POST requests. `STATIC_FILES_DIRS` not related to media files but option name is misspelled, it's `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Also STATIC_ROOT is not set and the value of STATICFILES_DIRS is most likely supposed to be STATIC_ROOT instead. `/media/img/sample.png` your folder structure does not have `img` subfolder, the links is anyway broken.